# Material-UI checkbox backrground color

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I am using material ui checkbox, i wanted it to have its own background color over my div which has colored background. I have set the root to have a backgroundColor as white but the svgicon is a round shape which is not the look i intend to have. Can i shape the checkbox ?

Already have tried many things but not able to figure out how to change the icon

```
const styles = {
    root : {
        padding : '0px',
        display : 'inline-block',
        backgroundColor : 'white'
    },
    formLabelRoot : {
        margin : '0'
    }
}
.
.
.
render () {
        const { classes } = this.props
        return(
            <div style={customStyles.divStyle}>
                <div style={customStyles.div1}>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        classes={{root: classes.formLabelRoot}}
                        control={
                            <Checkbox
                                classes={{root : classes.root }}
                                color='primary'
                            />
                            }
                        label={''}
                    />
                </div>
```

The background white is making a spherical rounded checkbox apparent

[Image of what is happening now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkxnv.png)

Comment: What color do you want the checkbox to be? Do you want it to be white? You'd need to the set the backgroundColor/background of the checkbox to match the background of the wrapping div/element. https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-rp2wu

Comment: I have solved this issue. I will update this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can override the icons used for the checked and unchecked states. The props you're looking for are `icon` for the unchecked state and `checkedIcon` for the checked state. Both of which take a component to be used as the icon.

Documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make a compromise here if you don't want to go making your own icons.
Something like this is possible without changing the icons. If you're looking for a solid white box with a grey outline as the unchecked box, you might have to provide that svg yourself because I don't see anything like it in `@material-ui/icons`.

[image]

If this IS something you're ok with then target the svg, and give it a `fill: "white"`.